# .Net SignalR Handling rapid requests from client to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

We have two .net apps that communicate through SignalR JSON protocol. The client often times needs to send rapid messages to the server in realtime (around 60 per second). The issue we are finding is that SignalR is not able to handle that many messages and seems to queue the messages. Often times, after halting the messages from the client, the server will continue to receive the queued messages (sometimes for a whole minute after the client is halted).

The server setup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddSignalR(o =>
     {
         o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
         o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null; //No limit
         o.MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient = 15;
         o.StreamBufferCapacity = 1024;
     })
         .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opts =>
         {
             opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
             opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
         });
 }

 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
     if (app == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         //endpoints.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/hub");
         endpoints.MapHub<SignalRHub>("/hub", options =>
         {
             options.Transports =
                 HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
         });
     });
 }
```

And the clients send the messages with `_hub.Send(functionName, parameters);`. We have tried using Send and SendAsync.

It is important that the messages can be sent in somewhat realtime and a queue system will simply not work for the app. We would prefer a delay in the send over a queue.

Can this be achieved with signalR? Or should we be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a performance issue. If you have an Azure subscription, you can try using Free Trial for testing.

Here is the limitation. You can use free trial for testing, if it works fine, then it's the performance.

[image]

#### Solution

1. Using Azure SignalR Service if you want.
2. [Set up a Redis backplane for ASP.NET Core SignalR scale-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-8.0)